# Dynamically adding columns via parameterised stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, procedure, dynamic-sql

I have a Project table which has Poject Start and Project End dates. I need to add the columns as Quarters into a new table Planned Cost where Quarters should be between the Project Start and End Dates.

Have wrote a procedure to dynamically add the columns based on the parameters which we are passing- Project and Business name. But the code is not working and giving the error.

Code :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ****
@Project_Name NVARCHAR(100) output, 
@Business NVARCHAR(100) output 
AS 
SET nocount ON 

    DECLARE @column NVARCHAR(20), 
            @SQL    NVARCHAR(1000) 
    DECLARE @ParamDefinition AS NVARCHAR(2000) 

    SET @column = N'select Q +cast(FLOOR(((12 + MONTH(Engagement_Master_FPA.[planned start date])) % 12) / 3 ) + 1  as varchar(4))+_+CAST(year(Engagement_Master_FPA.[planned start date]) AS varchar(4)) + from Engagement_Master_FPA where Engagement_Master_FPA.project=' 
                  + @Project_Name + ' and Business=' + @Business 
    SET @SQL = N'ALTER TABLE [[Planned_Cost_Master_FPA_BKP] ADD ' + @column + ' varchar(50)' 
    SET @ParamDefinition=N'@Project_Name nvarchar(100) ,@Business nvarchar(100)' 

    EXECUTE Sp_executesql 
      @SQL, 
      @ParamDefinition, 
      @Project_Name output, 
      @Business output 

    SELECT @Project_Name, 
           @Business
```

Error:

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'select'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
Incorrect syntax near 'varchar'.
```

(1 row(s) affected)

(1 row(s) affected)

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. (That code is product specific.)

Comment: Its SQL server.

Comment: Seems like bad design to me. As a rule of thumb, DDL should be used at design time, not at runtime.